# Skip focus on some hide fields on AG Grid

Tags: angular, focus, ag-grid

I am using Angular and AG-Grid and I have a table bellow

Normal
[image]

When the user hovers over a row, 2 hidden buttons will show up
[image]

Those buttons actually belong to the 2 hidden headers
[image]

The thing is when I use the tab to navigate through the table, I want to skip those hidden headers fields, for example, I am on `Description` when I continue to press `Tab` what I expect is it will skip 2 hidden headers and jump on to the hash value
[image]

I did a research but cannot find the solution for this.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `tabToNextHeader` [property](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/angular/keyboard-navigation/#tabtonextheader)

In template add the attribute and callback function as below:

```
[tabToNextHeader]="nextHeader"
```

In component file define the method. Here we are setting the focus to first column in the next row, by skipping the rest of the header columns. Note: This is a sample code, update accordingly.

```
nextHeader(params: any) {        
    const previousHeader = params.previousHeaderPosition;
    // Select the first column in the next row
    let nextColumn = previousHeader.column.columnApi.getAllColumns()[0];  
    if(previousHeader.column.colId === 'description' && params.backwards === false) {
      return {
        headerRowIndex: -1, // return a non-header row
        column: nextColumn,
      };
    }
    // TODO: Add logic for reverse tab, make use of 'backwards' field in params
    return params.nextHeaderPosition;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that a good idea, but I still stuck with case backwards from cell to header that function is not fired when the user backwards from cell to header